# Capistrano authentication to server fails but ssh for deploy user works

Tags: ssh, ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I've been working with capistrano for about a year deploying an app and everything went fine, until a couple of days ago when I got this

`** [server_name :: out] fatal: Authentication failed`

after typing deploy user's password. Trying to ssh using the same credentials works perfectly.

Do you have any idea about what could have caused this? I'm using capistrano (2.15.5) and ruby 1.9.3, and this is my Capfile:

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
# load 'deploy/assets'

Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin|     load(plugin) }

load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. I was using HTTPS authentication for Github, but the url changed. I switched to SSH, added the public keys of the deploy user to deploy keys and everything works fine now.